# SQL syntax error with joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Can someone point our what is wrong with below query? I have 3 tables.

```
1. Order Header - Order_header_id
2. Order Pricelist - order_header_id(fk),pricelist_id(fk) 
3. Pricelist - pricelist_id,Name
```

I am trying to get the pricelist name based on the order header using below query and it throws "missing right parenthesis" error. Not sure if I am in the right direction.

```
Select pricelist.Name from ORDER_HEADER
left outer join 
(select order_pricelist.pricelist_id from order_pricelist on order_header.order_header_id = order_pricelist.order_header_id 
left outer join 
(select pricelist.name from pricelist) pricelist on order_pricelist.pricelist_id = pricelist.pricelist_id)
```

Thanks

Comment: You're mssing a right parenthesis before your second 'left outer join' - exactly as the error says! Also, you should have an alias for it like you did for the second join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select pricelist.Name from ORDER_HEADER
left outer join 
(select pricelist_id, order_header_id  from order_pricelist) op 
   ON order_header.order_header_id = op.order_header_id 
left outer join 
(select name,pricelist_id  from pricelist) pr 
   ON op.pricelist_id = pr.pricelist_id
```

But actually, you don't need subqueries here, so it can be like this:

```
Select pricelist.Name from ORDER_HEADER
left outer join  order_pricelist op on order_header.order_header_id = op.order_header_id 
left outer join  pricelist pr on op.pricelist_id = pr.pricelist_id
```